# Basic Waypoint usage

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use the [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin for jQuery to lazy load elements on a webpage. However I can't get it to work.

I made a very basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/P3XnN/2/

According to the Waypoints documentation all I need to do is the following.

**JS:**

```
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function() {
   alert('You have scrolled to my waypoint.');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="height: 500px">Scroll down</div>
<div id="waypoint">Waypoint</div>
```

But it isn't as simple as that apparently. What can I try next?

Comment: It looks like it is as simple as that, you just need to scroll further: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/P3XnN/3/

Comment: Oh so the waypoint has to be at the top of the viewport.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The plugin docs reveal an [`offset` option](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#waypoint-options) that does the following:

> Determines how far the top of the element must be from the top of the
> browser window to trigger a waypoint. It can be a number, which is
> taken as a number of pixels, a string representing a percentage of the
> viewport height, or a function that will return a number of pixels.

You can pass options to the `waypoint` method as the 2nd argument:

```
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function() {
    alert('You have scrolled to my waypoint.');
}, {
    offset: '100%'
});
```

Here's an [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y75sgp0t/). Updated broken CDN resource 2022.

Comment: Many thanks! I prefer using offset: 'bottom-in-view' instead as it's more "readable" :)

Comment: @Snæbjørn - You're welcome, glad I could help :) Oh yeah, I didn't read enough of the docs to notice that... definitely better to use that than `100%`.