# Javascript Waypoints (or alternative)

Tags: javascript, scroll, infinite-scroll

I tryied to use the [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) library to fire an event when we scroll to the end of a div (in order to implement an "infinite scolling"-like functionality). I looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471781/basic-waypoint-usage) but it apparently doesn't work if I use a custom scrollable 'div', it only works for the window scrolling. Here my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qa68m10n/6/

```
 var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    console.log('waypoint')
  },
  offset: 'bottom-in-view' 
})
```

Am I right? Is there an alternative?

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549676/detecting-end-of-scroll-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do with Waypoints by setting the context option to the scrollable element.

```
<div id="overflow-scroll">
  <div id="context-example">I am a waypoint with a custom context, the "#overflow-scroll" div.</div>
</div>

<script>
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('context-example'),
  handler: function() {
    console.log('Context example triggered')
  },
  context: document.getElementById('overflow-scroll')
})
</script>
```

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/context-option/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32305483)